# Opening a JFrame within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a main JFrame with a button that generates another JFrame. However, when I close the 2nd JFrame the main JFrame is also closed which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably set default close operation to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` on both of JFrames.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The only way we can tell you what you are doing wrong is if you tell us what you are doing in the first place. Please post some code so that we can help you.

Comment: Ups...I almost forgot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice This question needs more attention.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  This seems better suited to a `JDesktopPane` with `JInternalFrame` objects inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're setting the default closing action as:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

The `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` constant terminates the whole program when you click the `x` button. You probably want to use `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` or `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` instead. I recommend to have a look at the [JavaDoc of JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html).

Comment: Thank you very much :-) `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` was the fault. It's baked into my brain like a mantra, hence I didn't think about changing it.